# How to show a image in React from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

```js
// JSON File
{
    "project": [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "title": "Old Portfolio",
            "images" :{
                "main": "portfolio.png",
                "second": ""
            },
            "content": ["This is one of my first few projects I made as a beginner", "At this project, I learned using JavaScript for making interactive elements like a navbar button. This project was not really something I'm proud of. Hence why I'm making a new portfolio but now with react"]
            ,
            "tags": ["HTML5", "CSS", "JavaScript", "jQuery"]
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Twitter Clone",
            "images" :{
                "main": "twitter_clone.png",
                "second": ""
            },
            "content": ["Project I made to improve my skills in PHP and MySQL.", "At this project, I used MySQL to store data and use PHP to alter what my website will show to the user. I've also used AJAX and JQuery for processing data from MySQL with PHP."]
            ,
            "tags": ["HTML5", "CSS", "JavaScript", "PHP", "MySQL", "jQuery", "AJAX"]
        }
    ]
}


// projectList is from a JSON file
// ProjectList.js
{projectList.map((project) => (
    <Projects key={project.id} projectData={project}/>
))}


// Projects.js
const imagePath = "../images/";
const mainImage = imagePath + projectData.images.main

const Projects = ({projectData}) => {
  <img style={{
      width: "100%",
  }} src={mainImage}alt="" />
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I have a JSON file that stores the images. This is gonna be for a list of projects.
The image src is not working and I can't import an image inside the function.
I hope someone could help I am new to React

Answer (score 1):

1. JSON should not be object, I guess in this case you can use array.
2. instead of using "img" you must use thumbnail, cause your object(project) has no "img" key, but has "thumbnail"->
   const mainImage = imagePath + projectData.thumbnail.main

```js
// JSON File

    [
        {
            "id": "0",
            "title": "Old Portfolio",
            "thumbnail" :{
                "main": "portfolio.png",
                "second": ""
            },
            "content": ["This is one of my first few project I made as a beginner", "At this project I learned using JavaScript for making interactive elements like a navbar button. This project was not really something I'm proud of. Hence why I'm making a new portfolion but now with react"]
            ,
            "tags": ["HTML5", "CSS", "JavaScript", "jQuery"]
        },
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Twitter Clone",
            "thumbnail" :{
                "main": "twitter_clone.png",
                "second": ""
            },
            "content": ["Project I made to improve my skills in PHP and MySQL.", "At this project I used MySQL to store data and use PHP to alter what my website will show to the user. I've also used AJAX and JQuery for processing data from MySQL with PHP."]
            ,
            "tags": ["HTML5", "CSS", "JavaScript", "PHP", "MySQL", "jQuery", "AJAX"]
        }
    ]



// projectList is from a JSON file
// ProjectList.js
{projectList.map((project) => (
    <Projects key={project.id} projectData={project}/>
))}


// Projects.js
const imagePath = "../images/";
const mainImage = imagePath + projectData.thumbnail.main

const Projects = ({projectData}) => {
  <img style={{
      width: "100%",
  }} src={mainImage}alt="" />
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you explain what was wrong and what you changed? Code-only answers are more likely to be downvoted.

Comment: 1. JSON should not be object, I guess in this case you can use array.

2. instead of using "img" you must use thumbnail, cause your object(project) has no "img" key, but has "thumbnail"->
const mainImage = imagePath + projectData.thumbnail.main

Comment: Please [edit] your answer with the new information.

Comment: in my code it's actually images, I just forgot to change it on my post but the problem is still the same.
When I put the main image path in the img src, the image doesn't appear. There's only gonna be like a broken image in the top left corner.

Comment: When I console.log it the path is right. And even if I hard coded the image src no images still appear

Comment: Do you get the expected result when you add image name manually in "const imagePath = "../images/";" this part?

Comment: Then your path is actually not correct. Can you correct location of your images?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a way,
I put the images on the public folder "public/images/image.png"
and

```js
const Projects = ({projectData}) => {
    <img src={`images/${projectData.images.main}`}/>
}
```